# Documentation Proposed Changes do not offer an option to search/view retracted proposals

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, proposed-changes

I wish to be able to search old suggestions in documentation to point to a discussion which happened in the comments there.

Additionally, and more importantly, we see approved and rejected suggestions, but not retracted suggestions, especially for:

- Finding an old comment (for example when it still applies to the new draft)
- Pointing out that an user is playing games (e.g. retracting often with unsubstantiated edits)
- To point out that something already has been proposed (and validly) retracted

Also, I'd be glad if I could view in an users documentation tab (i.e. user page -> activity -> documentation) what proposals and comments an user has ever submitted (including rejections and retractions) to see repeated offenders, and not just the proposals which were actually approved. It also will show myself a list of what was rejected, retracted and commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rejected proposals now remain listed in your profile (as drafts).

Comment: These doesn't count towards the draft limits, correct?

Comment: No more than before.